# Angular 2+: providing a single instance of a global service to sub-modules

Tags: angular

How can I provide a global service (e.g. providing data) and access it from the **submodules** in an  angular 2+ app? Here the emphasis lies on sub-modules. I know it's pretty straight forward with a component hierarchy tree, but I couldn't find any good explanation how that works with multiple modules.

For example, if we have the following app structure/hierarchy:

```
AppModule
  myservice
  AppComponent
  FeatureModule1
     ComponentA
     ComponentB
  FeatureModule2
     ComponentC
     ComponentD
     FeatureModule3
       ComponentE
```

Where do I have to provide the service? Just in `AppModule` or also in the submodules (`FeatureModule1`, `FeatureModule2` and `FeatureModule3`)? The same question about importing. 
To import and provide only on the root level doesn't work (`FeatureModule1` for example has no access to the provided `myservice` instance as far I've experienced.) 
Do I have to do the re-importing (eventually re-providing) on every hierarchy level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement forRoot() in the module where you defined your service or define it in your AppModule. Do not provide the service in multiple modules, because this will create multiple instances. My preferred way is to create a SharedModule which provide all shared services like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ... ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        MyService
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

In my AppModule I import it with forRoot():

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [
    ...
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in all other modules, I just have to import it without foorRoot.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Just for understanding, do I have to import the SharedModule also in `FeatureModule3`, even if it's imported already in `FeatureModule2`, meaning module imports are not propagated to sub-modules?

Comment: Module imports are propagated to sub-modules. But it don't hurt to import it 
 again in your submodule, so you can change your structure in the future without being afraid of breaking things ;-)