# Angular 6 Creating Singleton Service

Tags: angular, authentication, angularfire2, angular6

I understand there have been some changes in Angular 6 with the way singleton services have to be created. I have an Auth Service that needs to be constructed once for each component that accesses it. I set the provider to root for the service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

And in my app.module.ts file, I set AuthService as one of my providers in NgModule. However, whenever I route between different components that use the Auth service, it creates a new instance of the Auth Service (clearing data from the first time it was called). How do I ensure that the Auth Service is only instantiated once, and then access that instance among different components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the default behaviour of adding providedIn to the service level. As per [`Docs`](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#application-wide-dependencies)

> providedIn here tells Angular that the root injector is responsible
>   for creating an instance of the HeroService. Services that are
>   provided this way are automatically made available to the entire
>   application and don't need to be listed in any module.

in your case just remove the **`providedIn: 'root'`** and have only under provides in the module.ts. Refer the following **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174859/angular-6-service-with-interface)**.

Comment: I see. I do not understand how to then instantiate a global instance of the Auth service then. I get this error:  Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthService: (?).

Comment: *IMPORTS GO HERE*

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: any;
  constructor(private fireBaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 

    this.fireBaseAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if(user){
     console.log(user)
     this.user = user
    }else{

     this.user = undefined
    }
   });
  }

  userDetails(){
   if(this.user){
    return this.user;

   }
   else{
    return undefined
   }
  }

  isLoggedIn(){
   console.log(this.user)
   if(this.user){
    return true
   }
   else{
    return false
   }
  }
}

Comment: post in your code and the app.module.ts in the question

Comment: app.module.ts :   providers: [UserAuthorizedService, AuthService
  ], This code is still causing the AuthService to create multiple instances whenever I load another router or refresh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976399/angular-2-providing-a-single-instance-of-a-global-service-to-sub-modules

Comment: ah i see, thank you. will this persist through page refreshes as well? or must I use local storage in that case?

Comment: no when you refresh the page it will be instantiated again , yes you should go for a session storage

Answer (score 4):

To avoid any other confusion you can create singletons in two ways, just as stated in the docs ([singleton-services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#singleton-services)):

- Declare that the service should be provided in the application root.
  `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`.
  **The service should not be imported in any module then.**
- Include the service in the AppModule or in a module that is only imported by the AppModule.
  **Here no need to use `{providedIn:'root'}`**.

In my case singleton services did not work when using JIT (normal ng build / ng serve). For me it only worked when using AoT (ng build --aot / ng serve --aot).

Comment: Same Problem in Angular 8.  it is not working without aot flag. I had wasted 2-3 days for this simple flag. Why it does not work without aot?